# ACPI events delayed or not logged in Linux

Tags: linux, bios, acpi, lid

I have a samsung ultrabook (NP530U3C) that is not working good with ACPI events:

lot of ACPI events *randomly* stop to be logged on kernel messages either in acpid logging.

The lid closing is ever logged with 10 sec delay at least, and sometimes never logged at all.

I'm frustrated because iIcan't isolate the cause of the problems; sometimes occur to boot in the right way, sometimes not. Sometimes make a suspension solve the problems, somtimes start it. I found a quick way to *reset* the ACPI not logged using a needle pushing a button on bottom of the laptop.

The lid almost ever take 10 sec to be logged (one or 2 times it was not delayed).

i dunno how to debug it couse is really erratic and randomly applied...

here my dmesg:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/my4olxju2zz46mu/dmesg

Hope get some hints on it is drivin me crazy!